# Use SSL with HTTP

Tags: https, http

Just wondering,

is there a way to use SSL without HTTPS and run it on HTTP?

I don't want to know this to end up using this in production, but I'm just wondering to improve my knowledge of the possibilities with such protocols.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP + SSL = HTTPS

So, no, you cannot run SSL over HTTP.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further about the technical reason?

Comment: They are two different protocols. Each has its own specification. HTTP can't be secure without becoming HTTPS. I would recommend reading up on each at Wikipedia to learn the technical differences as it is a broad topic.